# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileRetrolambdaDebug' - After Firebase integration

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, rx-java2, retrolambda

I am creating an application with the support of Retrolambda & RxJava2. Everything works fine until I needed to implement push notification functionality. I have configured firebase in my application, since then the execution failed with below error message.

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithRetrolambdaForDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

**Top Level Build.gradle**

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.7.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Application level Build.gradle**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.solver.inventory"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 2
        versionName "Beta V2.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        //Use “exclude” to point at the specific file (or files) that Android Studio is complaining about//
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile(name: 'aficustomprint', ext: 'aar')
    compile('com.github.KingsMentor:MobileVisionBarcodeScanner:v1.2') { transitive = true; }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.6'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-appcompat-v7:0.4.0'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
retrolambda {
    javaVersion JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    jvmArgs '-noverify'
    defaultMethods false
    incremental true
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Everything works fine again if I remove the firebase from my application. Please help me out of this.

Comment: Did you tried compiling a different firebase version?

Comment: No I just used the latest version. let me try on previous version. I will update.

Comment: Actually I was using an older version, which was automatically added by firebase plugin in android studio. I just updated it to the latest version, but no luck

Comment: Does `retrolambda` work with out `firebase`?

Comment: Also, the Gradle Retrolambda Plugin's [README](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda) says **`mavenCentral()` is required because `retrolambda` is on maven central**. I wonder if writing `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` or `mavenCentral()` is same thing.

Comment: Yes it was perfectly working before firebase integration with the same Build.gradle files